# How to attach a excel workbook to slide in power point using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to attach an excel workbook at a specific shape index eg. sld.Shapes(19) in a PowerPoint slide using vba.

I'm trying this but not getting the desired result:

```
sld.Shapes(19).AddOLEObject _
ClassName:="Excel.sheet", fileName:="Standard_Sectors_template.xlsx", DisplayAsIcon:=msoTrue
```

Please help.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you need to be more specific. there is not a lot to go by with what you are presenting. what error did you get. where is the rest of the code that is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

First, as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addoleobject), you must specify either the ClassName or FileName argument for the object, but not both.  Secondly, you should specify a path for the file.

Accordingly, the following code will position the newly added workbook at the `sld.Shapes(19)` location.  Change the path accordingly.

```
Dim shp As Shape

With sld
    Set shp = .Shapes.AddOLEObject(FileName:="C:\Path\Standard_Sectors_template.xlsx", DisplayAsIcon:=msoTrue, Link:=msoFalse)
    With .Shapes(19)
        shp.Left = .Left
        shp.Top = .Top
    End With
End With
```